# github enterprise - Is it possible to get the title of the ssh key of another user

Tags: github-api

It is possible to get the title of my own SSH keys via the API

```
api/v3/user/keys
```

It is also possible to get the SSH key (the key itself and the key.id) for another user, via

```
api/v3/users/<userID>/keys
```

It seems I am restricted to the key and the key.id.

Is it possible to obtain the title of the SSH key of another user ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "no" as the title is considered as a private information.